# Regular expression to check if a string match certain pattern

Tags: java

How to use Java regular expression to check if a string follows a certain pattern ? e.g. to check if a message first starts with "`In the morning`", then followed by any words, then followed by "`In the afternoon`", and then followed by any words.

I have tried to look up the regex syntax but found it difficult to understand.

I have tried to use `|`, but this is an "Or" operator. And it does not specify the ordering of first matching "`In the morning`" and then "`In the afternoon`".

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bIn the morning\\b|\\bIn the afternoon\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("In the morning I read the news, then I start my work. In the afternoon I have my lunch.");
```

Comment: `In the morning.*?In the afternoon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yD1NP8/2)

```
String str = "In the morning I read the news, then I start my work. In the afternoon I have my lunch.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\bIn the morning\\b.*\\bIn the afternoon\\b.*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.matches())
    System.out.println("match");
else
    System.err.println("not match");
```

- `^` asserts position at the start of a line
- `\b` assert position at a word boundary: `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
- `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
- `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Answer (score 0):

`^In the morning .*In the afternoon.*`

The ^ matches the start of the expression to match. The .* matches zero or more non return characters.

You can also put parenthesis around the .* to form capture groups to find out what actually you did in the morning and afternoon

`^In the morning (.*)In the afternoon (.*)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `.*` in between the two phrases, rather than an alternation.  Try this version:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bIn the morning\\b.*\\bIn the afternoon\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("In the morning I read the news, then I start my work. In the afternoon I have my lunch.");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This prints:

```
In the morning I read the news, then I start my work. In the afternoon
```